# mysql memory exhausted when export the text file using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, database, mysql, export-to-csv

I am using codeigniter and mysql and trying to insert the values of one table say "accounts" into "summary" table. Accounts table contain more than 60K rows. The summary table is a temporary table, which store the temporary records based on some condition applied on "accounts" table during report generation.

To make the execution faster, I am looping the account table and creating the concatenated select statement using union. While I am creating the temporary records into summary. I am doing like below.

```
<?php
$flag = 0;
foreach ($accounts as $act) {
if ($flag == 1) {
$unionstr = " UNION";
}
$userData[] = "$unionstr" . " SELECT A.AcctDb,'" . $default->DeftReportPeriod . "', '" . $default->DeftReportBase . "', '" . $default->DeftPeriodBasis . "', '" . $default->DeftBasisAdj . "', '" . $AcctNo . "','" . $AcctTaxId . "', '" . $RevLoc . "', '" . $YTDStart . "', '" . $CurrFreq . "', '" . $Curr . "', '" . $Ytd . "', '" . $Lastcurr . "', '" . $LastYTD . "', '" . $Last12 . "', '" . $Prior12 . "', '" . $Last12diff . "', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '" . $Currdiff . "', '" . $Ytddiff . "', '" . $Mon['0'] . "', '" . $Mon['1'] . "', '" . $Mon['2'] . "', '" . $Mon['3'] . "', '" . $Mon['4'] . "', '" . $Mon['5'] . "', '" . $Mon['6'] . "', '" . $Mon['7'] . "', '" . $Mon['8'] . "', '" . $Mon['9'] . "', '" . $Mon['10'] . "', '" . $Mon['11'] . "','" . $Amt['0'] . "', '" . $Amt['1'] . "', '" . $Amt['2'] . "','" . $Amt['3'] . "', '" . $Amt['4'] . "', '" . $Amt['5'] . "', '" . $Amt['6'] . "', '" . $Amt['7'] . "', '" . $Amt['8'] . "', '" . $Amt['9'] . "', '" . $Amt['10'] . "', '" . $Amt['11'] . "' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = '" . $AcctDb . "' and A.AcctTaxId='" . $AcctTaxId . "'";
$flag = 1;
}
?>
```

After proper concatenated query, I am trying to write into the file.

```
$sql = implode(' ', $userData);
$date = date('m-d-Y-h-i-s-a', time());
$filename = $date . "file.txt";
$ext = mysql_real_escape_string("\r\n");
$sqlstatement = $sql . " INTO OUTFILE " . "'" . $filename . "'" . " 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY " . "'" . $ext . "'" . " ";

$query = $this->db->query($sqlstatement,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE); // This is unbuffered query
$query->free_result(); // The $query result object will no longer be available
```

the printed query is like below

```
SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '601849740','601849740', '2203', '201211', 'M', '0', '0.97', '0.1', '1.25', '0.97', '1.25', '-0.28', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '-0.1', '-0.28', '', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1', '0.09', '0.09', '0.08', '0.08', '0.08', '0.08', '0.08', '0.09','', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='601849740' UNION SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '601849740','601849740', '2207', '201211', 'M', '0', '0.13', '0.01', '0.12', '0.13', '0.12', '0.01', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '-0.01', '0.01', '', '0.01', '0.02', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.02', '0.01','', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='601849740' INTO OUTFILE '02-12-2014-12-26-41-pmfile.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Then, Reading the file and insert into the table "summary"

```
$sqlstatement1 = "LOAD DATA INFILE " . "'" . $filename . "'" . " 
INTO TABLE summary
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY " . "'" . $ext . "'" . " ";

$query1 = $this->db->query($sqlstatement1,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE); // This is unbuffered query
$query1->free_result(); // The $query result object will no longer be available
```

In short, I am inserting the temporary records into the summary table by using i/o statement using mysql. It works fine for having upto 5000 records, but it is not working for more than 5000 records. I am getting the below error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

memory exhausted near '.AcctTaxId='601487287' UNION SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '60148860' at line 1
```

If any input from stackoverflow community will help us to resolve the issue. For me, this is a critical production issue.

Comment: try if this helps http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/777/solve-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-8388608-bytes-exhausted-tried/

Comment: already seen the article, it does not help me to resolve the issue

Comment: I think there is no need of file i/o. You could write a single sql statement for select from accounts and insert into summary as:
insert into summary (
select ... from accounts where ...
union
select ... from accounts where ...
union
...
);

Comment: I tried that too as an another option., the page tooks much time to execute and displays the same error, then I tried the file i/o